# component does not render in block save

Tags: block-editor

I use the same custom 'Krug_broj' component both in edit and save functions, but it is rendered only in edit. How can I make it render in save? There are no errors on compile phase nor in the block editor. When I debug, call to component is simply skipped in save for reason unknown to me.

Edit:

```
import Krug from './images/Krug_broj.jsx';
export default function Edit({ attributes, setAttributes, context }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        attributes.buttonVariationNum = context['makeiteasy/buttonVariation'];
    }, [context['makeiteasy/buttonVariation']]);
    return (
        <article { ...useBlockProps() }>
            <div className="title-compound">
                <Krug number="46" variant={1}/>
                <RichText
                    aria-label={ __('Naslov elementa') }
                    placeholder={ __('Naslov...') }
                    value={ attributes.elementTitle }
                    onChange={ elementTitle => setAttributes({ elementTitle }) }
                    withoutInteractiveFormatting
                    tagName="h4"
                    multiline={ false }
                    allowedFormats={ [] }
                />
            </div>
            <RichText
                aria-label={ __('Odjeljak') }
                placeholder={ __('Upiši tekst...') }
                value={ attributes.elementText }
                onChange={ elementText => setAttributes({ elementText }) }
                tagName="div"
                multiline={ true }
            />
        </article>
    );
}
```

save:

```
import Krug from './images/Krug_broj.jsx';
export default function save({ attributes }) {

    return (
        <article {...useBlockProps.save()}>
            <div className="title-compound">
                <Krug number="46" variant={1}/>
                <RichText.Content
                    aria-label={ __('Naslov elementa') }
                    value={ attributes.elementTitle }
                    tagName="h4"
                />
            </div>
            <RichText.Content
                aria-label={ __('Odjeljak') }
                value={ attributes.elementText }
                tagName="div"
            />
        </article>
    );
}
```

Krug_broj component:

```
import { memo } from '@wordpress/element';

function Krug_broj_def(props) {
    switch (props.variant) {
        case 1:
            return (
                <svg viewBox="0 0 120 120" width="2.5em" height="2.5em">
                    <path
                        d="M63.84 116C94.86 116 120 90.78 120 59.66S94.86 3.32 63.84 3.32 7.68 28.54 7.68 59.66 32.82 116 63.84 116"
                        fill="#6294bc"
                    />
                    <path
                        d="M93.72 24.86c19.58 19.64 20.01 51.06.96 70.17s-50.37 18.68-69.95-.963c-19.58-19.64-20.01-51.06-.959-70.17s50.37-18.68 69.94.962m2.308-5.196c-22.05-22.13-57.71-22.23-79.64-.225-21.93 22-21.83 57.78.224 79.9 22.05 22.13 57.71 22.23 79.64.226 21.93-22 21.83-57.78-.225-79.9"
                        fill="#b0c9de"
                    />
                    <text
                        x={60.23}
                        y={80}
                        fill="#fff"
                        fontFamily="'Fira Sans'"
                        fontSize={68}
                        strokeWidth={2.308}
                        textAnchor="middle"
                        style={{
                            fontVariantCaps: "normal",
                            fontVariantEastAsian: "normal",
                            fontVariantLigatures: "normal",
                            fontVariantNumeric: "normal",
                            lineHeight: 1.25,
                        }}
                    >
                        {props.number.toString() + '.'}
                    </text>
                </svg>
            )
            break;
    }
}

const Krug_broj = memo(Krug_broj_def);
export default Krug_broj;
```

**EDIT:**
Suddenly, after multiple resave, it started working. I guess it is one of the quirks on relation Gutenberg -React

Comment: Check your browser console. The frontend does not load react by default. You have to make it a dependency. Also read this SO post to understand it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51771125/wordpress-gutenberg-react-components-on-front-end#answer-54411238

Comment: I am not using react in frontend. Only in save function, which gives static output